# Microsoft R OpenとRstudioの違いはなんですか？

Tags: python, r

Microsoft R OpenとRstudioの違いはなんですか？またどちらがおすすめなのかも教えていただきたいです。

Comment: マルチポスト　https://teratail.com/questions/107391

Answer (score 1):

Microsoft R OpenとRstudioはどちらかと言われれば、Rstudio 。理由はドキュメントの充実度。

結論としては、、、
Microsoft R OpenとRstudioはどちらもお勧めできません。インストールが楽ちんというメリットがありますが、「拡張性が低い」「マークダウンなどの機能が直感的でなく使いにくい」「ドキュメントが少ない」などのデメリットがたくさんあります。

使うなら今後のことも考えてjupyter notebook というものを使ってください。
jupyter notebookはもともとpython用に開発されたIpythonが発祥ですが、今はあらゆる言語に対応しています。若干環境構築手順が多いですが、断然おすすめ。

Comment: わかりました。ありがとうございます！